# Keras: how to make Keras train layers connected to merge layer

Tags: keras

I'm confusing about the mechanism of the merge layer in Keras.

For example, `branch_left` is a `Sequential()`model that contains two `dense()` layers while `branch_right` is another `Sequential()` model that has only one `dense()`. Then there is a `merge()` layer connect them in a `concatenate` way and I put the `merge` layer into a `Sequential()` model `merged_model`. Since I wanna get the name or weights saved in layers from those two `branch` model, I tried to call `merged_model.layers` and found the first layer is `merge` layer.

Considering `len(erge.get_weights())=0`, is there any way to get the layers existing in `branch_left` and `branch_right`? If that is possible, then I can modify the properties which are belonging to those layers.

Comment: You can access the weights separately by using the model they belong to : branch_left.layers[1].get_weights(). The Merge layer has no parameters in itself! Nothing trainable in a merge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure it's a good idea to put the merge layer into a sequential...
(Sequential models do not support branches)

The best to do is to create a functional API model:

```
from keras.models import Model

merged_model = Model([branch_left.input,branch_right.input],concatLayer.output)
```